# check number in array

Tags: java, performance

Fast way to check integer in the array. Array has not continuous integer in it, instead it has spatial numbers e.g. [1,4,11, 120,2,3].

In time efficient way, how do one check `3 in [212,31219,1,12,4]`? Result is false

Comment: I have implementation, iterate over array. For me it is slow. OTher recommendataion

Comment: What do you mean by "check integer in the array"? And what are "spatial numbers"?

Comment: If your array is not sorted, you'll have to iterate. You can also use `Arrays.asList(...).contains(...)`

Comment: It's provably impossible to do this without checking each item individually.

Comment: Why is O(n) (n being the size of the array) not good enough? I don't think there's any faster way.

Comment: For one or generally few checks there is no faster way (as far as i know). If you show us your concrete implementation we may spot a performance bottleneck...

Comment: You can use a `Set` (eg. [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)) In average case, it will be a check in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how often you need to check for a given integer.

1. If you have to check the same array over and over again it would be faster to sort it once and use a binary search algorithm to find your number (or not, if your number is not in the array).

   In Java you don't have to reinvent the wheel. You can use the static methods in `Arrays` for these tasks (N size of your array):

   `Arrays.sort(...)` will sort your array in ascending order. This sorts the array in `O(N*log(N))` steps.

   `Arrays.binarySearch(...)` afterwards will find your number in the sorted array. Finds your Element in `O(log(N))` steps.
2. If you check for a given value only once in a while you may simply iterate over the array. Finds your Element in `O(N)` steps.

Comment: The first search will still be O(n + log(n)) which simplifies to O(n) I believe, as you'll have to actually sort the array first and then run the binary search.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner sorting is `O(n*log(n))`

Comment: Yes, the first run will be in `O(n*log(n) + log(n))` for one sorting and one binary search. But the ongoing searches will only add a `O(log(n))` binary search step. That way the end complexity is `O(n*log(n) + m*(log(n)))` with m beeing the total number of checks. For fixed `n` and propably big `m` this results in fewer steps than the iterative approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches

Consider array of size N , and T searches

#### Linear search method

Complexity : `O (T * N)`

Sample code :

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 212, 31219, 1, 12, 4 };
        // perform searches from here
        // for eg.
        // boolean exists = contains(arr, 4);

    }

    public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == x) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Binary search method

Complexity : `O (N * log(N) + T * log(N)`

Sample code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 212, 31219, 1, 12, 4 };

        // sort array first => complexity O(N * log(N))
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        // perform searches from here
        // for eg.
        // boolean exists = contains(arr, 2);       
    }

    public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int key) {
        return Arrays.binarySearch(arr, key) >= 0 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

So if your number of searches is very high use binary search method else use linear search method.